# Any solution to "Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly?"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

The name is defined in all my component instances with the correct capitalisation but I still get the error, I've found many similar problems online but the problem always seems to be with the name, however I'm 100% sure all my components have exactly the same name as those in the routes.js folder. Anyone have any ideas for possible solutions? Thanks.

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-link to="/search"></router-link>
        <router-view> </router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Search from './components/Search.vue';
import Apod from './components/Apod.vue';
import News from './components/News.vue';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound.vue';
export default {
  name: 'app', 
  components: {
    NotFound: NotFound,
    Search: Search,
    Apod: Apod,
    News: News
  }
}
</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: VueRouter,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Apod from '@/components/Apod';
import Search from '@/components/Search';
import News from '@/components/News';
import NotFound from '@/components/NotFound';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/apod',
        name: 'Apod',
        component: Apod,
    },
    {
        path: '/search',
        name: 'Search',
        component: Search,
    },
    {
        path: '/news',
        name: 'News',
        component: News,
    }
]
})
```

Search.vue

```
<template>
<div class="search">
    <h2> Search: </h2>
    <h5>Home</h5>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="getResult(query)">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" v-model="query"/>
    </form>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="results"  >
            <div class="row" v-for="(r, index) in Math.ceil(results.length / 4)" v-if="index <= 3">
                <span class="result" v-for="result in results.slice((r - 1) * 4, r * 4)">
                    <img :src="result.links[0].href" :alt="result.data[0].keywords[0]"/>
                    <p class="text"> {{ result.data[0].title }} </p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
name: 'Search',
data() {
    return {
        query: '',
        results: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    getResult(query) {
        axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=' + query + '&media_type=image')
        .then(response => {
            this.results = response.data.collection.items;
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main your should write:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from './path-to-your-router-init-file';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: VueRouter,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I've updated that, I'm still getting the same error though :(

Comment: Did you import router from your index.js? Is it has right export name? I mean, you export `Router` but import `VueRouter`

Comment: Also, I didn't see your `router-view` element

Comment: Updated all that, thanks again. I just get 2 errors now though, one for the router-link and one for router-view, the same as before saying "unknown custom element".

Comment: Okay, looks like you don't have component for default path `/`. But main idea, you cannot use `link` outside `view` element

Comment: So I have to have the router-link element within the router-view element?

Comment: I checked docs, you may use `link` outside `view` but this looks odd to me. Btw, your `link` missed text content to render. It will be simple `a`, but no text is given. Maybe this is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for checking,  but I've added some text to it and it still gets the same error :(

Comment: You forget to update your `main.js` file or you still import VueRouter from npm package?

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot Sergey, think it actually was that I wasn't changing the name of the router I imported between the index.js and main.js. Think I was still importing the one from the npm package like you said. Thought I'd tried changing the names already but just tried again and it worked. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yeah, no porblem